# Regular expression for matching a specifc substring of a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a log file that logs connection drops of computers in a LAN. I want to extract name of each computer from every line of the log file and for that I am doing this: `(?<=Name:)\w+|(-PC)`

The target text:

```
 `[C417] ComputerName:KCUTSHALL-PC UserID:GO kcutshall Station 9900 (locked) LanId: | (11/23 10:54:09 - 11/23 10:54:44) | Average limit (300) exceeded while pinging www.google.com [74.125.224.147] 8x

[C445] ComputerName:FRONTOFFICE UserID:YB Yenae Ball Station 7C  LanId: | (11/23 17:02:00) | Client is connected to agent.`
```

[image]

The problem is that some computer names have `-PC` in them and in some isn't. The expression I have created matches computer without `-PC` in their names but it if a computer has `-PC` in the name, it treats that as a separate match and I don't want that. In short, it gives me 3 matches, but I want only 2. That's why I need help here, I am beginner in regex.

Comment: Could you please add your regex and your test case as text rather than images ?

Comment: just did now here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=Name:)\w+(?:-PC)?
```

**Details**

- `(?<=Name:)` - a place immediately preceded with `Name:`
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?:-PC)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of `-PC` substring.

Consider using word boundaries if you need to match `PC` as a whole word,

```
(?<=Name:)\w+(?:-PC\b)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ip9Wkv/1).

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot :)